# Bash - How to run code whenever USB device is connected

Tags: python, linux, bash, keyboard, usb

I am writing a bash script to automatically detect when my USB keyboard is plugged into my laptop (running Ubuntu 14), so I can change the keyboard layout automatically.

Here is my code so far (I got it from another post on Stack Overflow so I'm not 100% sure how it works)

```
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap es
for dev in /sys/bus/usb/devices/ *-*:*
do
    if [ -f $dev/bInterfaceClass ]
    then
        if [[ "$(cat $dev/bInterfaceClass)" == "03" && "$(cat $dev/bInterfaceProtocol)" == "01" ]]
        then
            setxkbmap gb
        fi
    fi
done
```

I have got this to run on startup so far... But I'd like it to run every time a USB device is connected or disconnected.

**It is important that I have it all run in one Bash script** and not as a  .rules file in ...udev/... or anything. However, a single Python script will do just as well.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/284224/autorun-a-script-after-i-plugged-or-unplugged-a-usb-device

Comment: @M. Becerra that is not what i am looking for.. "It is important that I have it all run in one Bash script and not as a .rules file in ...udev/... or anything."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [ralf htp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5230735/ralf-htp) I was able to come up with the following solution.
It has the following improvements:

- It is not dependent on specific keyboards, it will treat all USB keyboards in the same way.
- If the user manually switches to a different keyboard layout (one which is neither the default or the USB keyboard's) it will not automatically switch it back to the default or USB layout.

Please feel free to improve this code at [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/abrahammurciano/312a75430d9fc99c5786c974d1439628)

```
#!/bin/bash
kbd1=es #default keyboard layout
kbd2=gb #USB keyboard layout

flag=0
while true
do
    layout="$(setxkbmap -query | grep -a layout | cut -c13-14)"
    if [[ $layout == $kbd1 ]] || [[ $layout == $kbd2 ]]
    then
        for dev in /sys/bus/usb/devices*-*
        do
            if [ -f $dev/bInterfaceClass ]
            then
                if [[ "$(cat $dev/bInterfaceClass)" == "03" && "$(cat 
$dev/bInterfaceProtocol)" == "01" ]]
                then
                    if [[ "$flag" == "0" ]]
                    then
                            setxkbmap $kbd2
                    fi
                    flag=1
                    break
                fi 
                if [[ "$flag" == "1" ]]
                then
                    setxkbmap $kbd1
                fi
                flag=0
            fi
        done
    fi
    sleep 5s
done
```

Answer (score 1):

this works because on linux system the file system structure is always the same

`cat $dev/bInterfaceClass` queries every usb device for its *interface class*

`cat $dev/bInterfaceProtocol` queries every usb device for its *interface protocol*

try `ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/` and you see all usb device nodes

then select one i.e. `ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1` and use `ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/idVendor`

instead of `bInterfaceProtocol` i would use `idVendor` and `idProduct` you can determine product ID and vendor ID of your keyboard by attaching the keyboard and using `lsusb` and picking it from the listing

UPDATE

following script will do it. insert the vendor and product id of your device. maybe test before without the `setxkbmap` command. the `flag` variable is used for not settingthe keyboard map every 5 seconds ...

```
#!/bin/bash

flag=0


while true

do

for dev in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*-*
do
    if [ -f $dev/idVendor ]
    then
        if [[ "$(cat $dev/idVendor)" == "your_vendor_id" && "$(cat $dev/idProduct)" == "your_product_id" ]]
        then
            if [[ "$flag" == "0" ]]
              then
                echo 'USB device attached'
                 setxkbmap gb
            fi
            flag=1
            break
        fi 
            if [[ "$flag" == "1" ]]
               then
                 echo 'USB device detached'
                 setxkbmap es
            fi
            flag=0
    fi

 done

  sleep 5s

done
```

note that for `setxkbmap` to be working you have to install `x11-xkb-utils`

( https://superuser.com/questions/404457/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-while-in-console )

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, but that doesn't really answer my question. I am asking how i can have it detect when the usb is plugged in or out, so it can change whenever i plug in the keyboard, as opposed to only once (on startup)

Comment: I guess this does the trick, however it doesn't seem very orthodox to check every 5 seconds​... Is there not a way to run every time a USB device is attached or detached?

Comment: I decided to use this one, but I kept the interface class and protocol instead of the vendor and product ID. I put it into a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/abrahammurciano/312a75430d9fc99c5786c974d1439628

Comment: updated answer above and deleted the other version below because the SIGPIPE mechanism is not working reliably. polling every 5s is very CPU saving...

Comment: Why have you repeated almost the same code twice? why is it better than how it was before? This seems to run the code once, then run it again every 5s in a loop. What's the point of having the first run not in the loop?

Comment: the code before the loop sets the `flag` variable that is necessary to determine  if the device is attached or not attached *when the script is started*. this is the only purpose of the code before the loop...

Comment: That's not necessary. The first iteration of the loop will do that anyway.