# Make a program USB Copyer with bash shell linux

Tags: bash, shell

This is my code that I made to copy all fd data to the `home/user` directory with bash shell

```
#!/bin/sh
user=$(whoami)
now=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S")
dir=$(mkdir $now) --> and here I want to create a folder as a place to copy the results according to datetime

if [ -d /media/$user/foo ]
then
    echo "any media"
    cp -r /media/$user /home/$user/$dir
else
    echo "none of media attached"
fi
```

but i run thats code, `cp -r /media/$user /home/$user/$dir` not running as well, which is not copied to the newly created directory based on datetime , any advice ? or
something's wrong in my code ?

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
dir=$(mkdir $now)
```

with

```
mkdir "$now" || exit 1
dir="$now"
```

This will terminate your script if there is a problem with the directory creation.

Comment: Or use `mkdir -p`.

Comment: I will try it sir, and if possible I ask if there is a way to run the sh program in the background so that when the usb is detected it will automatically run the sh program

Comment: I put it in the bashrc file but it only runs when the terminal is opened

Comment: This might help: [How to execute a shellscript when I plug-in a USB-device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65891/74329) or [Bash - How to run code whenever USB device is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43265185/3776858)

Comment: I've read it but I understand nothing, but thank you for giving a suggestion